# Declension ending "-er" of the adjective Berliner

Tags: adjective, gender, adjective-ending, definite-article

Why does

> die Berlin*er* Mauer

use the adjective with ending *-er*? Why isn't it

> die Berlin*e* Mauer

This should be right, but it is not. Why?

Comment: Why do you think that the latter would be right? All possible declensions of the adjective _berliner_ are _berliner_, never _berline_. See https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Berliner#Adjektiv.

Comment: Well, there's some gap in my knowledge. I use the analogy with other adjectives. I don't see the difference between die gute Frau and die berline Mauer. Mauer and Frau are feminine. They control the ending of the adjective... or they don't? And adjectives like berliner have their own declensions?

Comment: die gut*e* Frau, der gut*e* Mann, das gut*e* Kind

Comment: @Oleg "gut" vs. "berliner" is not a good comparison since "gut" is a standalone adjective, but "berliner" is one derived from a noun (Berlin). Location-noun-to-adjective derivations especially can be very tricky, as there are various patterns (berliner, berline, berlinerische, berlinische, berlinesische...) and you basically have to know which one applies by heart (there are some rules of thumb though).

Comment: Proper nouns do not decline the same as adjectives, even when used in the same fashion. *Die Chinesische Mauer, das Schweizer Taschenmesser, das Bermuda-Dreieck.*

Answer (score 0):

All declension forms of the adjective [*berliner*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Berliner#Adjektiv) are *berliner*. None form is
*berline*. That's why it is

> die Berlin*er* Mauer